# Convergence of the sequence $a_n=\frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}+\dots+\frac{1}{(2n)^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

What I did is,
$$n\frac{1}{(2n)^2} \le a_n \le n\frac{1}{n^2}$$
Can we conclude that $a_n \rightarrow 0$ using squeeze theorem. Is there any mistake?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\frac{n+1}{(2n)^2}\le a_n \le \frac{n+1}{n^2}$$

And, yes your conclusion is right!